# Unable to create DataFactoryManagementClient() using DefaultAzureCredential?

Tags: python, authentication, azure-data-factory

I use `DefaultAzureCredential` for all Python dev up to this point (KeyVault clients, BlobStorage clients, etc). This is my first time working with azure.mgmt.datafactory in Python. When trying to use `DefaultAzureCredential`, I get the error: `AttributeError: 'DefaultAzureCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'`.

**To Reproduce:**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
rg_name = 'RG_ADF_SANDBOX1'
df_name = 'df20201019test'
df_resource = Factory(location='westus')
df = adf_client.factories.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, df_resource) #<----ERROR HERE
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because azure-mgmt-datafactory has not been updated to use azure.core. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate?tabs=cmd#defaultazurecredential-object-has-no-attribute-signed-session.

This documentation provide two alternatives:

1. Use one of the other authentication methods describe in subsequent
   sections of this article, which can work well for code that uses
   only SDK management libraries and that won't be deployed to the
   cloud, in which case you can rely on local service principals only.
2. Instead of DefaultAzureCredential, use the CredentialWrapper class
   ([cred_wrapper.py](https://gist.github.com/lmazuel/cc683d82ea1d7b40208de7c9fc8de59d)) that's provided by a member of the Azure SDK
   engineering team. Once the desired management library is available,
   switch back to DefaultAzureCredential. This method has the advantage
   that you can use the same credential with both SDK client and
   management libraries, and it works both locally and in the cloud.

You can also create a data factory by using this code:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *
import time

#Create a data factory
subscription_id = '<Specify your Azure Subscription ID>'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='<Active Directory application/client ID>', secret='<client secret>', tenant='<Active Directory tenant ID>')
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

rg_params = {'location':'eastus'}
df_params = {'location':'eastus'}  

df_resource = Factory(location='eastus')
df = adf_client.factories.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, df_resource)
print_item(df)
while df.provisioning_state != 'Succeeded':
    df = adf_client.factories.get(rg_name, df_name)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you. Is there a way to used System-assigned Managed Identities with this library? It doesn't appear so.

Comment: No, there isn't this way.